# Text not changing with render_template after adding Ajax in Flask App

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-wtforms

I created a simple AJAX to send data to a flask route without refreshing the page, the data seems to get to the route but it isn't changing the text after render_template.

MyForm is a simple dropdown. I'm trying to display the text of the current selection after form submitted or button clicked without refreshing the page by using AJAX.

**run.py**

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, jsonify
from forms.myform import MyForm
import json
import plotly
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

server = Flask(__name__)

server.config.update(dict(
    SECRET_KEY="powerfulsecretkey",
    WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY="a csrf secret key"
))

@server.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    choice = request.form.get('options')
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        choice = request.form.get('options')

    print(choice)

    return render_template("index.html", form=form, choice=choice)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```

**form**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import wtforms


class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    options = wtforms.SelectField(label="State", choices=[("SF", "SF"),
                                                          ("LA", "LA")])
```

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="fm" action="/">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div>{{ form.options}}</div>
</form>
<button type="submit" form="fm" value="Submit">Submit</button>
<div>{{ choice }}</div>
</body>

<footer>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
          $('form').on('submit', function(e){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:$('form').serialize(),
                    url: '/',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR) {
                        alert("error: " + jqXHR.status);
                        console.log(jqXHR);
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault();
             });

            // Inject our CSRF token into our AJAX request.
            $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ form.csrf_token._value() }}")
                }
            }
        })

    </script>
</footer>


</html>
```

**Browser**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you are a form submitted by ajax，The page is not re-rendered，Jinja2 is a rendering to take effect